# Got errors when changing a readonly file (the CSS of pop-out dictionary) on OS X

Tags: macos

When I tried to edit a CSS file to adjust the pop-out font through vim in terminal, I got
`W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file`. Thinking sudo could be used to tackle that, I went editing the file anyway.

```
body {font-size: 12pt;} → body {font-size: 14pt;}
```

But then I couldn't save the change. 
I tried a command suggested online `:w !sudo tee %` and got

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 2
```

How to improve that command?

`/System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/3300e8c78ceb9a7ceeb617334b1df9018e6b46b8.asset/AssetData/Oxford\ American\ Writer\'s\ Thesaurus.dictionary/Contents/Resources/DefaultStyle.css`

macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to edit a file within a restricted location, protected by System Integrity Protection.

```
$ ls -O /System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX
total 104
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  restricted  224B 19 Apr 09:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 24 root  wheel  restricted  768B 31 Mar 12:15 ../
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  restricted  160B 31 Mar 12:19 2fcc349eb53d7c336b8372758b70508eb8e2ac0b.asset/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  restricted  160B 31 Mar 12:19 61b49f47f0dce1c061c688d415e1f1a84c37fce0.asset/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  restricted  160B 31 Mar 12:19 cd4d7cc1cd227a13d2b9c029f86c940f94b7543a.asset/
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  restricted  3.4K 19 Apr 09:29 com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  restricted   44K 19 Apr 09:29 com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX.xml
```

These cannot be edited even with sudo. To edit files within restricted locations, either:

- Perform the edit from Recovery HD.

  1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
  2. Use the Terminal from the Utilities menu in Recovery to perform the edit. Note that / is the mount point of the recovery environment, therefore you should access your disk from `/Volumes/yourdiskname/…`.
  3. Reboot
- [Disable System Integrity Protection](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/), perform the edit, then re-enable it.

  > 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
  > 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
  > 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
  >
  >    ```
  >     csrutil disable
  >    ```
  > 4. Restart.

  5. Perform the edit you wish to make to the files.
  6. Boot into Recovery HD once more and run `csrutil enable` to re-enable SIP.

Comment: I'd tried both. Don't know why but wrong path for the first method, as the terminal opened a blank new file for me. As for the second method, change still wasn't allowed to keep after successfully csrutil disable; this time the error message is 'E212: Can't open file for writing'. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @afternoon Method 1: Did you provide the right path with the name of your disk under /Volumes? Check you’ve got the right path with `ls`? Method 2: Just because you’ve disabled SIP doesn’t mean your account has got write access to the file, it’s still not owned by you so you’ll need to sudo to edit it.